# Otherwise values as option in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
session = (spark.table(f'nn_team5_{country}.fact_table')
              .filter(f.col('date_key').between(start,end))
              .filter(f.col('is_client_plus')==1)
              .filter(f.col('source')=='session')
              .filter(f.col('subtype')=='events')
              .groupby('customer_id')
              .agg(f.countDistinct('ga_session_id').alias('total_sessions'))
              .withColumn('session_count',
                         f.when(f.col('total_sessions')>=3,'+3').otherwise('total_sessions'))
             )

display(session)
```

I have the following output:

```
customer_id  sessions  session_count
484635        2        total_sessions
483635        40        +3
484005        1        total_sessions
484688        3        +3
184635        4        +3
```

My ideal output would be:

```
customer_id  sessions  session_count
484635        2          2
483635        40        +3
484005        1          1
484688        3         +3
```

Does someone know how to do it in order to get just the counting in the otherwise part? I used the new column created in the alias but it took it as literal not as the values inside the different cells.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `f.col` to specify that you want the column, not the string literal.

```
session = (spark.table(f'nn_team5_{country}.fact_table')
              .filter(f.col('date_key').between(start,end))
              .filter(f.col('is_client_plus')==1)
              .filter(f.col('source')=='session')
              .filter(f.col('subtype')=='events')
              .groupby('customer_id')
              .agg(f.countDistinct('ga_session_id').alias('total_sessions'))
              .withColumn('session_count',
                         f.when(f.col('total_sessions')>=3,'+3').otherwise(f.col('total_sessions')))
             )
```